# Mongodb not connected using service name

Tags: typescript, mongodb, docker, kubernetes

I am using Kubernetes. For the MongoDB instance, I used a prod and a service. But when I want to connect MongoDB using the service name I got the connection error. But I am able to connect using the service cluster IP address.

This is my service description

```
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
auth-mongo-srv   ClusterIP   10.105.37.75     <none>        27017/TCP   19s
```

This is MongoDB connection code

```
try {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://auth-mongo-srv:27017/auth');
    
    console.log("Connected with MondoDB !!!");
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

This is my console error

```
[INFO] 17:23:25 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.1, typescript ver. 
4.8.4)
[auth-service] MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out
[auth-service]     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri 
(/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:824:32)
[auth-service]     at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:381:10
[auth-service]     at 
/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
[auth-service]     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
[auth-service]     at promiseOrCallback 
(/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
[auth-service]     at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback 
(/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1234:10)
[auth-service]     at Mongoose.connect 
(/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:380:20)
[auth-service]     at /app/src/index.ts:13:24
[auth-service]     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
[auth-service]     at /app/src/index.ts:8:71 {
[auth-service]   reason: TopologyDescription {
[auth-service]     type: 'Unknown',
[auth-service]     servers: Map(1) { 'auth-mongo-srv:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
[auth-service]     stale: false,
[auth-service]     compatible: true,
[auth-service]     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
[auth-service]     localThresholdMS: 15,
[auth-service]     setName: null,
[auth-service]     maxElectionId: null,
[auth-service]     maxSetVersion: null,
[auth-service]     commonWireVersion: 0,
[auth-service]     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
[auth-service]   },
[auth-service]   code: undefined
[auth-service] }
```

Comment: Are they running in the same namespace ? why dont you try with FQDN name
auth-mongo-srv.{namespace}.svc.cluster.local ?

Comment: @AvinashJha Yes, I am using the same namespace. auth-mongo-srv and ingress service both are running on the ingress-nginx namespace.